# How to get last one record from multiple rows

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `test_series_records` Where one users have multple rows, I want the last created record per user, Like if one user has 4 records in the table, then the last or recent record should select. I want to show all the records available in the table but the last record per use. How can I achive that?

I have tried this-

```
$result = TestSeriesRecord::groupBy('user_id')
->where('test_id', $id)
->orderBy('correct_answers', 'DESC')
->get();
```

But It's give an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'scordemy_db.test_series_records.total_questions' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: Please check the below answer and let me know if it's working or not.

Comment: It is working but the record I got is the first one, not the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this hope it will work. Creating a subquery and running it before, so that results are ordered as expected and grouped after.

```
$sub = TestSeriesRecord::orderBy('correct_answers','DESC');

$result = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
->where('test_id',$id)
->groupBy('user_id')
->get();
```

Comment: It is working but the record I got is the first one, not the last one

Comment: Can you please fix this?

Comment: So you have to place wrong field in orderby. you have to place id field of correct answer or created_at date field for accurate answer, Other wise according to correct_answer it will orderby latters because you store string values in that field

Comment: If you not understand then share me testSeriesRecord table

Answer (score 0):

Try this `latest();` method:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#latest-oldest

```
$result = TestSeriesRecord::where('test_id', $id)->latest()->first();
```

And Remember this will only work when have default `created_at` column in your table

Comment: It's returning the last one records, I want to fetch all the records with no duplicate entries, If same user id has multiple records, I need the last record from multiple entries.

And the if you don't have default created_at then you can simply put the column name where has the created date into the latest()

Comment: Okey try  change  `first()` to `get()` or `all()`  it will return all

Comment: Uff, It's not the thing I want. Please read the question